# Почему при увеличении масштаба в Chrome у блока с разными значениями `padding-top` и `padding-bottom` снизу появляется полоса?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Как убрать полоски, появившиеся из-за `padding`?

При увеличении масштаба со 100% до 120%, полоска пропадает, а со 130% до 150% вновь появляется. Похоже, что Google Crome что-то неправильно считает?

Обращаю ваше внимание на то, что если для блока задать разное значение `padding-top` и `padding-bottom`, внизу появляется полоска толщиной около 1 px.
Если задать одинаковые значения для `padding-top` и `padding-bottom`, то полосок не будет.
Также замечу, что это работает в Google Chrome. В Opere не работает. В других браузерах, кажется, тоже.

После добавления первого блока сверху, появится полоска снизу каждого обычного блока.

ВНИМАНИЕ! Через эту функцию исполнения кода **"Выполнить код"**, баг воспроизводиться не будет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>None</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
        <span style="display: block; padding-top:2px;  padding-bottom:1px; background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
    </div>

    <div style="width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
        <span style="background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
        <span style="background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; background-color:black;">
  <span style="display: block; padding-top:2px;  padding-bottom:1px; background-color:black;">тестовое слово</span>
</div>

<div style="height:30px;width:100%; background-color:black;"></div>
<div style="height:30px;width:100%; background-color:black;"></div>
```

---

Если постепенно уменьшать или увеличивать масштаб в браузере в Google Chrome, то появляются горизонтальные полоски между обычными div. Подобное поведение не повторяется в других браузерах.
Был сделан запуск index.html с рабочего стола.

Судя по всему, поведение воспроизводится, если у вас **х64** операционная система.
Яркость монитора делайте побольше, а то не увидите полосок...

Вот код:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>None</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background-color:black;">
    </div>
    <div style="height:30px; width:100%; background-color:black;"> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вот еще один пример:**

Прошу заметить, если мы устанавливаем 'padding: 20px 14px **19px**;' и запускаем через файл html, а не программу для демонстрации кода в этом сообществе, то полосы будут  проявляться в браузере, а в программе для демонстрации кода , нет. **Но**, если мы изменим значение на 'padding: 20px 14px **20px**;', то в программе для демонстрации кода, появятся полосы, а при запуске  через html файл, полосы исчезнут. Если мы еще опустим значение на единицу 'padding: 20px 14px **18px**;' , то опять, запуск кода через html файл приведет к  исчезновению полос, а в программе для демонстрации кода, полосы вновь появяться. И так далее....

---

**Нет** - нет полос

**Да** - есть полосы

```
------------------------------------------------------
                 Браузер |  Программа для демо. кода |
------------------------------------------------------
20px 14px 20px   Нет   | Да  
20px 14px 19px   Да    | Нет
20px 14px 18px   Нет   | Да
20px 14px 17px   Да    | Нет
  ......
------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Тоже самое происходит при изменении масштаба страницы браузера.**

Следовательно, тут проявляется связь, между изменением значений **padding** и увеличением масштаба страницы браузера.

Вывод: судя по всему GoogleChrom, неправильно производит расчет, между некоторыми элементами.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <style>
        div {
             margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #333;">
        <div style="padding: 20px 14px 20px; ">
            test
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #333;">
        <div style="padding: 20px 14px 20px;">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вам не кажется, что если "_через эту функцию исполнения кода "Выполнить код", баг воспроизводиться не будет._", то проблема где-то еще? (Возможно в наложении стилей или стилях по умолчанию.)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev а вы html код смотрели?  Дочитали ли вы до конца мой вопрос?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev потому что прежде чем ставить минус, вы бы сначала подумали об ответе. Вопрос интересный, а вы сразу его опускаете. Да, кроме dimgrey и darkviole, там еще есть другие.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev Ваш вопрос, увы, сводится к "что у меня не так" и бесполезен в такой формулировке для всех, кроме вас. - Вы это решили за других людей, которым мог бы помочь ответ,  в заданном мной вопросе.И, ваш ответ не верный.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev кстати, что бы их увидеть , можно еще увеличивать размер данных в окне браузера. Но и без увеличения тоже порой работает.

Comment: "_порой работает_"? Это как? Сегодня работает а завтра нет? Или все зависит от удачи?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev "порой работает" - это у одних пользователей работает, а у других  нет.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev сейчас я немного перепишу свой вопрос

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вообщем позже, там не все так просто.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev При увеличении от 100% до 120%, полоска пропадает, от 120% до 150% вновь появляется. Похоже что GoogleCrom неправильно считает.

Comment: У меня такая же проблема в табличной верстке email-рассылки. Между tr-ками. Удалось решить проблему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поведение воспроизводится на всех браузерах с движком webkit, в том числе и в Opera.
В данном случае, оно не связано с разными значениями `padding-top` и `padding-bottom`, как вам могло показаться, и абсолютно не зависит от разрядности ОС.

Все дело в масштабировании.

Причина подобного поведения: [субпиксельный рендеринг](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit).

[image: субпиксельный рендеринг]

Представим, что клетки, на рисунке выше, — это пиксели.

Синий прямоугольник демонстрирует **фактическое** расположение вашего блока после масштабирования. Черный прямоугольник демонстрирует **рассчитанное** расположение одним из двух способов.

Об этом подробнее расскажу ниже, переведя часть статьи, доступной по ссылке, указанной выше. Сразу сделаю сноску, что у меня далеко не идеальный английский, поэтому возможны неточности. Прошу поправить меня, в случае ошибки.

#### Преобразование субпикселей в пиксели

При преобразовании прямоугольника с субпиксельной точностью расположения к прямоугольнику с целочисленной точностью  используется один из двух методов:

Суть первого метода, описанного в функции `enclosingIntRect`, заключается в том, что подбирается минимально возможный прямоугольник с целочисленной точностью отображения, который полностью включает в себя оригинальный субпиксельный прямоугольник. Таким образом, результирующий прямоугольник гарантированно будет либо такого же, либо большего размера, чем оригинальный. Этот метод уже какое-то время используется в WebKit для конвертации субпиксельных прямоугольников.

Второй метод заключается в выравнивании оригинального объекта внутри пиксельной сетки и называется привязкой к пикселям. Он описан в функции `pixelSnappedIntRect`. В этом случае, сначала применяется округление к координатам верхней левой логической точки прямоугольника, а затем остальные точки прямоугольника выстраиваются по сетке с уже рассчитанным смещением и привязкой к ближайшим пиксельным границам. Полученный прямоугольник получается выровненным по пиксельной сетке настолько близко к оригиналу, насколько это возможно, но не обязательно полностью включает в себя оригинал. Иными словами, после округления результирующий прямоугольник может оказаться меньше оригинального.

#### enclosingIntRect

Когда ведется расчет с помощью этого метода, к точкам на левой и верхней гранях прямоугольника применяется функция `floor`, а к точкам на нижней и правой гранях — `ceil`.

Значения рассчитываются следующим образом:

```
x: floor(x)
y: floor(y)
maxX: ceil(x + width)
maxY: ceil(y + height)
width: ceil(x + width) - floor(x)
height: ceil(y + height) - floor(y)
```

#### pixelSnappedIntRect

Данный метод позволяет гарантировать, что все грани выровнены по пиксельной сетке и что размер объекта, включая границы, отличается максимум на один пиксель.

Значения рассчитываются следующим образом:

```
x: round(x)
y: round(y)
maxX: round(x + width)
maxY: round(y + height)
width: round(x + width) - round(x)
height: round(y + height) - round(y)
```

Скорее всего, во время масштабирования вы столкнулись с проявлением действия второго метода субпиксельного рендеринга.

В пользу этого предположения говорит описание поведения 
[InlineBoxes in a RenderBlock](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/LayoutUnit#Usecases) все из той же статьи. Там значится тип отображения `pixel, snapped`. Кроме того, при смене инлайновой модели отображения `span` на блочную, данное поведение больше не наблюдается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35421/discussion-between-venzell-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте на span `display: block;`

```css
 span {
   display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
  <span style="display: block; padding-top:2px;  padding-bottom:1px; background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
</div>

<div style="width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
  <span style="background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; background-color:dimgrey">
  <span style="background-color:darkviolet">тестовое слово</span>
</div>
```

Comment: не верно. Смотрите. Для начала покрасьте все в background-color:black; а фон оставьте белым. И вы все увидите.

Comment: но тут не видно

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, так может проблема в вашем тестовом окружении? ;)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev если такая проблема возникла  у меня, то и у других пользователей она тоже будет. Да, конечно, не у всех.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов, а вот тут вы не правы. Ваша проблема в том, что inline span неверно (вам так кажется) определяет свою высоту. Поскольку в вопросе вы не вводите никаких ограничений на пути решения, то смена `display` на `block` это одно из решений (пусть и не самое лучшее).

Comment: `span` c `display:block` это `div`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890172/span-with-display-block